# Why is this POST request failing from Postman?

Tags: mysql, express, heroku, post, postman

Backend of my app is deployed on Heroku using Cleardb addon.

Below is the Backend code: For what I can tell it is hitting the POST requst.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
//const mysql = require("mysql");
//this was the old way and did not support secure password 
mysql = require('mysql2');


const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

/*
local connection 

const db =  mysql.createConnection({
    connectionaLimit: 50,
    user:'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    password:'',
    database:'sys',
    port: 3306
});

*/


const db =  mysql.createConnection({
    connectionaLimit: 120,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    port: 3306
});


app.use(cors());


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

//SQL connection test
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log('MySQL Connection Established.');
  });
  
/* not used get request
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send('Hello back');
}

);
*/


app.post('/' , (req,res) => {
    const {email, name, question} = req.body;
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log(`Your Email is ${email} and your name is ${name} and your ${question}`);



//MYSQL updating table

db.query("INSERT INTO customer_questions (name, email, question) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    [name, email, question], (err,result)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            res.send('data sent')
        }
        db.end();
    }
    );


});
 


app.listen(port);
console.log(`server is listing on ${port}`);
```

This is the error log.  From what I can tell it the server runs and then stops and the post request hits status 500.  I can tell why this is happening.
[image]

Post request using POSTMAN showing body.
[image]

Any help on this would be helpful.  The MYSQL connection works both locally and through Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [connection pool](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools) and don't close the connection:

```
db.end();
```

You can run querys on the pool object and it will take care of opening/closing connections for you.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it from closing.  I knew it had to deal with connection pools, however didn't know how to implement it.  Thanks for the documentation.